# how to override or change woo-commerce taxes according custom plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on custom shipping plugin.In that we are using API's to fetch taxes and as per this API response we have to override/change woo-commerce default taxes which set in setting of woo-commerce [woo-commerce tax settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PfwN.png).

Already tried this below function to `add_tax()` but its adding different row on checkout page [checkout-page details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlWxv.png) (highlightd in black colour in image).

`$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Tax', $tax_getting_from_api, true, '' );`

`$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Duty', $duty_getting_from_api, true, '' );`

Referance - https://woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/